# how check if element exists in array?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to check if `track_id` exists on an array?
Here is the array Structure, i tried use `indexOf`.

```
{"playlist":[{track_id : 1}, {track_id : 2}, {track_id : 3}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** method

```js
var obj = {
  "playlist": [{
    track_id: 1
  }, {
    track_id: 2
  }, {
    track_id: 3
  }]
};

var search_id = 2;

var found = obj.playlist.some(function(v) {
  return v.track_id == search_id;
});

console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function with a callback for [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
function check(id) {
    return data.playlist.some(function (a) {
        return a.track_id === id;
    });   
}

var data = {"playlist":[{track_id : 1}, {track_id : 2}, {track_id : 3}]};

console.log(check(5));
console.log(check(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that `indexOf` will not check by value for Objects, but by reference.

Example :

if :

```
var obj = { a: "a" };
var array = [ { a: "a" }, { b : "b"}];

array.indexOf(obj); //False
array.indexOf({ a : "a"}); //False
```

But if :

```
array = [obj, { b : "b"}]
array.indexOf(obj); //True
```

Knowing that you can use `indexOf` with Objects.
Otherwise, `.some()` seems to be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hasOwnProperty()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/328kyd6z(v=vs.94).aspx)

for check if key exist in you array object

Like this :

```
var object = {"playlist":[{track_id : 1}, {track_id : 2}, {track_id : 3},  {d : 3}]};
for (var key in object.playlist) {

    if(object.playlist[key].hasOwnProperty("track_id"))
    {
        console.log(object.playlist[key].hasOwnProperty("track_id"));
    }
}
```

```js
var object = {"playlist":[{track_id : 1}, {track_id : 2}, {track_id : 3},  {d : 3}]};

for (var key in object.playlist) {
    
    if(object.playlist[key].hasOwnProperty("track_id"))
    {
        console.log(object.playlist[key].hasOwnProperty("track_id"));
    }
}
```